# Flutter android app unexpectedly closes with "Lost connection to device" message?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Flutter app closes unexpectedly in android with "Lost connection to device" message. What are the possible causes of this bug?

Flutter version - v1.9.1+hotfix.4, 
Dart version - 2.5.0

Dart: Capture logs,

```
Dart Code extension: 3.5.1 
Flutter extension: 3.5.1 (not activated)
VS Code: 1.38.1
Platform: win
Workspace type: Flutter
Multi-root?: false
Dart SDK:
  Loc: D:\Flutter_SDK\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
  Ver: 2.5.0-edge.1ef83b86ae637ffe7359173804cbc6d3fa25e6db
Flutter SDK:
  Loc: D:\Flutter_SDK\flutter_windows_v1.2.1-stable\flutter
  Ver: 1.9.1+hotfix.4
HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
```

Comment: What happens if you run it a second time. This I found to work even though it is just a temporary workaround.

Comment: i dont think its a bug.maybe your cable disconnected

Comment: Also what plugins are you using, one could be causing the problem

Comment: @Taio the same.. it closes, plugins are -  carousel_pro: ^1.0.0
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  rxdart: ^0.22.2
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^0.4.3
  intl: ^0.15.8
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0

Comment: @Ggriffo, No way...

Comment: This is a bit tedious but, comment out all those plugins. Or the ones you have added before that error came up. Then run the app without the plugins you'll find the culprit eventually because I bet one of the plugins is causing the problem

Comment: First time I am facing this one.. I used these plug-ins before with no issues!